# What was the relation between mutants and sisters in short story "The Little Sisters of Eluria" by Stephen King

Tags: short-stories, stephen-king, the-dark-tower

I'm currently reading Stephen King's short story collection, *Everything's Eventual*. Last night I read the short story "The Little Sisters of Eluria" in it and have few questions regarding the plot.

What happened to the folks of Eluria before Roland arrived there?
Did mutants first attack the town and then sisters came to hunt the remaining alive, or did mutants come later from the near by mines after sisters killed the town people? Or do they both work together and attack new towns?

Note : I have already read the *Dark Tower* series.

Comment: Multiple questions need to be broken up into multiple posts.

Comment: @phantom42 Okay, 1 and 2 are related and so 3 and 4. I will divide them into 2 separate questions.

Comment: @phantom42 done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Dark Tower wikia page for Eluria:

> Shortly after his arrival Roland discovers Eluria is actually not
>   deserted after all and is inhabited by a gang of Slow Mutants. After
>   he is attacked and severely injured Roland is taken to a group of
>   nurses called the Little Sisters. During his stay with the little
>   sisters he discovers not only are they actually vampires but they also
>   killed off the entire population of Eluria.

http://darktower.wikia.com/wiki/Eluria

I don't think there is anything that explains this further, but I believe we are meant to understand that The Sisters killed off the town and that the slow mutants are merely occupying the town now since it was vacant.

Comment: Thanx for the reply, i think you are correct. It seems that sisters killed off the town because Ronald did not find body of any townsman just blood marks on beds. He also mention that mines are near by so mutates must have came from there afterward. I have up vote your answer.

Comment: @Deepak: You can also accept sanpaco's answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons if you think it is correct.